# What are the references for different active set selection methods for sparse Gaussian processes?

Tags: matlab, gaussian-process, sparse

I am comparing the different sparse Gaussian process approaches within the fitrgp function in Matlab, but I am struggling to find references for the different choices within the function for the active set selection. There are 4 options:

1. Random selection (which I understand is a poor choice)
2. Sparse greedy matrix approximation - I have a reference for this (Smola & Bartlett, 2001, 'Sparse greedy Gaussian process regression') but struggling to understand the application.
3. Differential-based entropy selection - I have come across a couple of references but not related to sparse Gaussian processes.
4. Subset of Regressors log likelihood-based selection - I have struggled to find references related to this.

I am aware of the paper by Titsias, 'Variational learning of inducing variables in sparse Gaussian processes', but haven't come across code for implementing it in Matlab, unless it is related to one of the above options?

Does anyone have any suggestions for the active set selection methods within sparse Gaussian processes, and how to implement them in Matlab?

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be a Matlab implementation [here](http://cogsys.imm.dtu.dk/passgp/), maybe can be adjusted for sparse cases. Regarding evaluations, there is also a technique for measuring performance of sparse Gaussian Process models, authored by myself [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02978)